# R: How to output a column based on the same formula for each input column?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

In the [latest DataFramesMeta.jl package for Julia](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFramesMeta.jl/pull/171) one can do

```
x = [:x1, :x2]
n = [:n1, :n2]
@transform(df, cols(x) = :y .+ cols(n))
```

and it will output the columns `x1 = y + x1` and `x2 = y + x2`.

The question, how best to do that in R elegantly? I can do it like this

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(y = 1:3, n1 = 1:3, n2 = 1:3)

x = c("m1", "m2")
n = c("n1", "n2")

code = glue::glue_data(list(x=x, n=n), "{x}=y+{n}")
code = glue::glue("vars({paste(code, collapse=',')})")

mutate(df, !!!eval(parse(text=code)))
```

or in Base

```
res = lapply(n, function(n) {
  df$y + df[, n]
}) %>% data.frame

names(res) <- x

df = cbind(df, res)
```

But it feels hacky. `data.table` and Base solutions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
df[x] <- lapply(df[n], function(p) df$y + p)
df
#  y n1 n2 m1 m2
#1 1  1  1  2  2
#2 2  2  2  4  4
#3 3  3  3  6  6
```

Similarly with `purrr::map` :

```
df[x] <- purrr::map(df[n], ~df$y + .x)
```

and `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (x):= lapply(.SD, function(p) p + y), .SDcols = n]
```

---

Late realisation that we don't need any apply family of functions, we can directly do.

```
df[x] <- df[n] + df$y
```

Comment: Variation on a theme - `df[x] <- Map("+", df["y"], df[n])`

Comment: I just realised we don't need any kind of `apply.*` here. `df[x] <- df[n] + df$y` should work right?

Comment: Indeed, though in reality I suppose the `+` function might be a lot more complex.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sweep`

```
df[x] <- sweep(df[n], 1, df$y, FUN = `+`)
```